# DataBindingUtil.setContentView() takes 500 milliseconds

Tags: android-databinding

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() called with: savedInstanceState = [" + savedInstanceState + "]");

    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_sensors);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()2 called with: savedInstanceState = [" + savedInstanceState + "]");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String address = intent.getStringExtra(ADDRESS_KEY);
    ....
}
```

04-22 16:51:55.553 7595-7595/my.app D/SensorsActivity: onCreate() called with: savedInstanceState = [null]
04-22 16:51:56.053 7595-7595/my.app D/SensorsActivity: onCreate()2 called with: savedInstanceState = [null]

The time between onCreate() and onCreate()2 is 500 milliseconds and that shows in the app... 
can anyone hint why does that happen? 
many thanks!

Comment: Is it a problem with data binding or is it an inflation issue? Try just Activity.setContentView() and let us know the time.

Comment: You are right! setContent view also took a long time 450 millisecionds

Comment: 50ms is also a very long time for data binding to do it's work. Assuming that you are using a phone and not some very slow device (e.g. watch it non native emulator), it could be that you have a very complex layout. Is your layout in the thousands of views?